# how to know if the SQL DB's records have been updated manually or directly (not via the web application used)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have an SQL database with ASP MVC web application, is there any way to know if someone executing SQL Queries directly with SQL server or not ?

for example, how to detect if there's someone has executed an sql operation (CRUD operation) directly not via the web application.

I mean I want to get all of the queries that have been executed to the database but not through of the Web Application.

that would help me to know if someone had changed the database records directly (not with web application) to the database in the Past.

Thank you !

Comment: You can't get this information retroactively. What you could do is create a trace (Extended Events) that captures rpc and batch completed events with a filter to exclude your app activity (e.g. by login and/or hostname).

Comment: Manage permissions! No one but the real superuser should be able to do things like that. Keep prod backend's login-password in secret.

Comment: One way to do this is to log changes thru a trigger, in this trigger you can do `select APP_NAME()` which will get you some information. But to get this working properly you need to add `Application Name=xxx;` in your connectionstring. Its not an easy way and it must be done on all tables you want to monitor